# Is the Problem of Universals still a prominent topic of debate?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, platonism, universals, nominalism

The [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy includes an entry for the Medieval version of the debate of universals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/universals-medieval/), but not for anything contemporary. There's an entry on [universals in the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/universa/), but the most recent surveys it cites are from the '90s. Has this debate faded from prominence, or morphed into different debates under different names? Can anyone suggest good contemporary sources?

Thanks!

Comment: It goes under "abstract objects" lately, see [Wetzel, Types and Tokens (2009)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/types-and-tokens), [Ehring, Tropes (2011)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00048402.2013.788047), [Moltmann, Abstract Objects (2013)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00048402.2013.840324), [Cowling, Abstract Entities (2017)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Abstract_Entities/w9QNDgAAQBAJ?hl=en), [Abstract Objects (2020)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030382414).

Comment: thanks @Conifold, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @Conifold 's comment, here is a list of SEP articles which seem to contain contemporary off-shoots of the original "Problem of Universals". If anyone has a suggestion to add to the list, that would be awesome!

- [Abstract Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/)
- [Types and Tokens](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/types-tokens/)
- [Tropes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tropes/)
- [Nominalism in Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nominalism-metaphysics/)
- [Platonism in Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism/)
- [Properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/)
- [Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object/)
- [Ontic Structural Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structural-realism/#OntStrReaOSR)
- [Reism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reism/)

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't fit. Still wrapping my mind around the Problem of Universals.

Comment: Since this is essentially a link-only answer, it would be *awesome* if there was a short text to each link explaining how this fits with the problem of universals. Not everyone will be acquainted with all these terms and we want to have as much knowledge as possible available here, on StackExchange itself. Cheers.

Comment: @JD seems like a great fit. Thanks for adding it, I was not aware of that article!

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I understand the concern. As I learn more about the subject over the coming weeks, I will try to improve the response.